# Spring Boot - How to read environment variables from file.conf

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a small problem. I want to be able to read/load environment variables from a myFile.conf-file from embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot and use these inside application.properties. Like so:

/config/myfile.conf (this file is not inside application.jar)

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
DB_USER=myUser
DB_PASSWORD=password
...
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.username={DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password={DB_PASSWORD}
```

and also that Spring automatically sets profile to whatever is in SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE environment variable.

How do I do this for a Spring Boot application that uses embedded tomcat? I know that this is easily done with en external tomcat installation by putting these variables in tomcat.conf

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thanks. I've read this part of the documentation earlier, but I cannot find the section that refers to what I want to achieve.

Comment: @benbjo and what's wrong with `@PropertySource("file:/AbsolutePathTo/myfile.conf")` and `spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
    spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}` in `application.properties` ?

Comment: Nothing, but using the environment variable SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE wont work. 
I can do what you suggest and pass -Dspring.profiles.active, but that is not exactly what I want to achieve. 
We have other applications that use external tomcat that put these variables in tomcat.conf. I basically want the same behavior for embedded tomcat. If that is not possible, Ill have to go with your suggestion I guess

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Specify **spring.config.name** environment property

Comment: Thanks, but that would be the same as using @PropertySource which does not do everything I want. This might be the way to go though